# Beautiful bent triangles

Tags: geometry

$x°, y°, z°$ are angles of tight rope triangle $ABC$. A killer bully bent its sides one degree each. So he got a concave hexagon with $(x-1)°, 181°, (y-1)°, 181°, (z-1)°, 181°$ as its angles. Prove that points of bending divided the sides of original triangle in the same ratio.

It surely does sound nice, but I struggled for a long time to solve it. I tried to use similarity and coordinates, but then realized sides can't be streched. I'm still trying, but completely stuck.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how this bending is being done here.  When you said the triangle was made of rope, I thought that would mean that it was being deformed in such a way that the perimeter remained constant, but after reading the rest of the question I'm not too clear on that.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the following illustration, where angles are exaggerated:

[image: Illustration]

The triangle $A'B'C'$ may be your original triangle, or a shrunken version thereof. In any case, it has the same interior angles as the original triangle $ABC$.

You have $\angle A'DB'=\angle B'EC'=\angle C'FA'=179°$. So $\angle B'A'D+\angle DB'A'=1°$. But at the same time, $\angle DA'F=(x-1)°$ so $\angle B'A'D+\angle FA'C'=1°$. If you combine them, you get $\angle DB'A'=\angle FA'C'$. Doing the same for other angles you find

$$\angle DB'A'=\angle EC'B'=\angle FA'C'\\
\angle B'A'D=\angle C'B'E=\angle A'C'F$$

So all three triangles $\triangle A'B'D,\triangle B'C'E,\triangle C'A'F$ are similar.

Since the argument above only uses angles, it doesn't matter whether the corners $ABC$ stay in their original positions and the rope is stretched, or whether the sum of the lengths for each original edge remains the same and the triangle as a whole gets scaled down a bit to obtain the new corners satisfying $\lvert A'D\rvert+\lvert DB'\rvert=\lvert AB\rvert$.

Of course, I started by assuming a triangle $A'B'C'$ similar to $ABC$. You might well challange that assumption. Having $A'B'$ similar to $AB$ is no big feat, since *any* line segment is similar to any other. So assume $A'B'$ to be all right, and then consider alternatives for $C'$. If $A',D,B'$ are known, then you also know the rays $A'F$ and $B'E$ but you might have some freedom of where on these rays you choose $E$ and $F$. More specifically you have two degrees of freedom, but you must choose them so that the edge sums for the two remaining original edges are satisfied again, which amounts to two constraints. Two degrees of freedom minus two constraints leaves you with no freedom at all.

The game changes if the corners of the triangle are just pegs, and the rope can move around them. In that case, the perimeter as a whole would have to remain constant, but for each edge the perimeter might change. I believe that in this case, your claim would no longer be true, since you'd have enough freedom to choose a different bending point for each edge.